# JSX: Expression inside another expression in a prop value

Tags: reactjs

I need to do the following in React:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name={props.name + 'Hidden'} 
       value={formik.values.{props.name + 'Hidden'}} />
```

This is illegal, but I need my inner `values` content, `value={formik.values.[..]`} , to dynamically refer to what `name` is referring to: `props.name + 'Hidden'`.

In other words, `value={formik.values.approverNameHidden}` works fine, and is the result of the prop `name=approverName`. But this is a shared component and it needs to be dynamic. How to do it in JSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
<input 
    type="hidden" 
    name={props.name + 'Hidden'} 
    value={formik.values[props.name + 'Hidden']}
/>
```